# Boost with libressl

Tags: c++, boost, openssl, boost-asio, libressl

Problem:

Boost defaults to using OpenSSL, but I need to switch to LibreSSL. I've replaced OpenSSL libraries with LibreSSL libraries, and the build succeeds. However, at runtime, I'm encountering an exception:

```
EXCEPTION: :context: Invalid argument [system:22] Exiting
```

Details:

I have successfully replaced the OpenSSL libraries with LibreSSL ones, using libraries with the same names. Despite the successful build, I'm facing this runtime exception.

Attempts to Solve:

- Replacing OpenSSL with LibreSSL libraries.
- Ensured correct linkage during the build process.
- Tried various configurations while building Boost.

Question:

How can I correctly configure Boost to use LibreSSL instead of OpenSSL without encountering runtime exceptions? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: When you say Boost, do you mean Boost Asio?

Comment: for ssl I use boost/beast/ssl.hpp

Comment: Could you please share your sample code? Are you using TLS v1.3?

Comment: https://github.com/boostorg/beast/blob/develop/example/http/server/async-ssl/http_server_async_ssl.cpp
Here I changed ssl::context ctx{ssl::context::tlsv12}; --> ssl::context ctx{ssl::context::tlsv13};

Comment: Its worked fine with TLS v1.2